# How to append elements to a vector without changing its size?

Tags: r, vector, for-loop, append

I want to add elements to a vector without changing its length. The vector should only contain 500 rows (1 column) after every for-loop. Here's what I have so far.

```
# initialize the vector
values<- vector(mode = "integer", length= 500)

for (i in 1:500) {
values<-append(values, 2i, after = i-1)
}
```

So the `values` vector should contain the following elements: `2,4,6,8,10, ... 998, 1000`

The problem with the append function is that if I add an element to the vector, it changes the length of the vector by 1. So at the end of the for-loop, the `value` vector would be length 1000 instead of 500, and contain the elements: `2,4,6,8, ... , 998, 1000, 0,0,0 [followed by zeros]`.

Is there another R function that will what I expect it to do, or is there a way I can fix my code above?

Thanks any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you would like to replace elements of the vector with different values.

Comment: Appending is adding additional elements, and so will increase the length. As @Seth said, you want to replace elements.

Comment: yeah that's what I want to do. is there a function for that?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but if you're confused about assigning values to a subset of a vector, then you would really benefit from fixing yourself a hot drink and spending 60-90 minutes with the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors), which will answer most basic questions like this.

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I'm a beginner in R. thanks for your help. I'll read the manual later this evening.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just trying to point you towards something helpful. Don't try to absorb the whole manual; just read it enough so that you'll remember reading about something relevant and know where to look it up again.

Answer (score 3):

A number of issues

- A vector has only length, not rows and columns
- For 2 times i, `2i` is not the r code you are looking for, you would  want `2*i`, `2i` will give you the complex number `0+2i`.
- you are looking for the function `` `[` ``( **Extract or Replace Parts of an Object**)

Are you just trying to create a vector `2,4,6,...,998,1000` if so then

```
values <- seq(2,1000,by=2)
```

will work.

`append` will append, and thus (by definition in `R`, as well as English) create a vector which is longer than the original.

For your loop to work as intended

```
# initialize a vector of 0's
values <- rep(0L, 500)

for (i in 1:500) {
  # replace the ith element with 2i
  values[i] <- 2*i
}
```

for an array

```
values <- array(rep(0L,500), dim = c(500,1))

 for (i in 1:500) {
  # replace the ith element in the first column with 2i
  values[i,1] <- 2*i
 }
```

Look at `` ?`[` `` for details on how to extract or replace elements of vectors, lists, arrays, data.frames etc

If you want a matrix with 500 rows and 1 column filled with `2,4,6,8,...998,1000`

```
values <- matrix(seq(2,1000,by=2), nrow = 500)
```

Comment: No, I would like to know how to replace elements in an array. The elements in the vector was just an example.

Comment: I've added an example for an array. You are looking for `[`. `append` is not what you want!

Comment: @user1313954: replacing elements is covered in mnel's answer -- see where the vector is addressed by index.

Comment: ah I see. thank you mnel. I'm sorry guys. I'm a beginner in R.

Comment: No worries. R can be opaque, so don't be hard on yourself. Just want to add a note to remember that R is 1-indexed, instead of other languages like C, Perl etc. where indexes are 0-based. In other words, `myArray[0]` in C would be `myVector[1]` in R.